# get custom input and store in MySQL in telegram bots

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm working on a shopping telegram bot written in laravel used by [irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk) package.

I know that how to implement keyboards , inline queries and get update messages.

But what I want to make is a few different. I want to get some information like **name** and **family**(But I do not want use `User` **first_name** and **last_name** provided with telegram API ) , **father name** and an **address** as simple text.

In this case I want first show a message `Send Me your name and family` then user enters her name and family and I store those in MySQL table. second another message like `send me your father name` and so on.

But I do not find any explanation for that no in telegram API no in mentioned package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ForceReply](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?sendMessage-5dd64378), and check [replied message text](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?getUpdates-835df2af).

Comment: I tried `$this->replyWithMessage([
    'text'         => 'Please enter your name ? ',
    'reply_markup' => [
     'force_reply' => true
    ]
   ]);` But it got this error : ` Array to string conversion {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Array to string conversion at D:\\wamp\\www\\botshop\\vendor\\irazasyed\\telegram-bot-sdk\\src\\Api.php:1445)`

Comment: How would one do this with a webhook?